# C++ Std::find() fails over generics/pair

Tags: c++, c++11

The given Error when I am passing in a type as string from the non generic driver class using C++11 (psuedocode below, can't really provide a compilable small example):

```
stl_algo.h|135|error: no match for 'operator==' in '__first.std::_List_iterator<_Tp>::operator*<std::pair<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> > >() == __val'|
```

I have a vector of Generic type

```
template <typename A, typename B>
vector<list<pair<A,B>> > myList;
```

I am trying to insert/remove elements from this list of pairs and am running into this type of error.

```
.#include <algorithm>

template <typename A, typename B>
bool addToList(const pair<A,B> &searchPair){

    auto & tempIndexList = myList[0];
    auto itr = std::find(std::begin(tempIndexList),std::end(tempIndexList), searchPair.first);  //Line where error occurs

}
```

I have tried changing from 'searchPair.first' to just 'searchPair' and it still fails with the same error. I'm thinking it has something to do with the fact that it is const, but I'm not really sure as it doesn't seem like it should be causing an error.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: I guess problem is that it can't compare list<pair<A,B>> with pair<A,B>

Comment: Are you saying that what it's doing is trying to compare Vector[List] with the pair rather than comparing Vector[List[Pair]] with the pair?

Comment: Still can't figure it out, hopefully someone else replies :(

Comment: I was not exactly right, you compare A with pair<A, B>, try searchPair instead of searchPair.first

Comment: I've tried both of the options, yet it still fails (see my last sentence in the post). Not sure what else to try

Comment: Actually I might be wrong on that last note. Will have to add it in everywhere and see if it fixes it permanently

Comment: It works for me without first: https://ideone.com/cxU3CE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::find` is trying to match the list's `value_type` (i.e. `pair<A, B>`) with just the first member of the pair, i.e. type `A`.

I'm guessing you're using this as some sort of flat map, so you actually want to check whether the first member of the pair is already in the list. In this case, you can use `std::find_if` to specify your own comparison predicate, e.g.

```
std::find_if(std::begin(list), std::end(list),
             [&searchPair] (const auto& val) {
                 return val.first == searchPair.first;
             });
```